# Postgresql order of records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of records in a table. I get records via select without any order statements just `select * from table` so there isn't any obvious order.

Will the order of records differs after updating some records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no internal order in a Postgres database table (and this is also the case with most other RDBMS).  The only order which will exist at selection time is the one you specify using an `ORDER BY` clause.  So, the answer to your question is that you should always rely on `ORDER BY` if you want a consistent, reproducible order in your result set.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. From PG documentation: "After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen."